# How to Change Ruby Font Output Color?

Tags: css, ruby

How can we make the Ruby output gold, while keeping the text (goals & accomplished) default black?

```
<div class="stats">
 <a href="<%= following_user_path(@user) %>">
  <strong id="following" class="stat">
   <%= @user.goals.unaccomplished.count %>
  </strong>
   Goals
 </a>
 <a href="<%= followers_user_path(@user) %>">
  <strong id="followers" class="stat">
    <%= @user.goals.accomplished.count %>
  </strong>
    Accomplished
 </a>
</div>
```

I tried adding it via a `<div>` class but then the positioning gets distorted, instead of being on one line, the text `Goals` drops a line below `.count`.

```
<strong id="following" class="stat">
 <div class="gold">
  <%= @user.goals.unaccomplished.count %>
 </div>
</strong>
  Goals
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? You've already got classes on the strong tags that you can use.

CSS:

```
body  {color:black;}
.stat {color:yellow;}
```

Comment: Thank you! I used .stat for other things as well but I made stat2 and copy and pasted code plus added the color. Thanks :)